# Пирожки с котятами

Tags: фразеология

Каждый из нас слышал такое шутливое выражение: "Вот такие пирожки с котятами", в смысле "такие дела". Но интересно было бы знать, откуда это выражение пошло? Я могу предположить, что в нем идет речь о, как говорится, "купи пять беляшей и собери кошку", но интересно, почему "пирожки с котятами" употребляются именно в этом значении? Наверняка у фразы есть какой-то первоисточник.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно,  просто  развитие  выражения "вот  такие  пироги". По  смыслу  совпадает.

Answer (score 1):

"А потом?" - "А потом суп с котом".

Ну а теперь пирожки с котятами. :)

Answer (score 1):

Исходное выражение: "Вот такие пироги с котятами. Их едят, а они пищат" - употребляется в тех случаях, когда происходит нечто непредвиденное, причем события раскрываются в процессе неожиданным образом (и не в лучшем смысле). Употреблялось абстрактно, юмористически - на Руси кошек в еду никогда не употребляли.
Предполагаю, что чувствительные люди сократили данную фразу до поговорки "Вот такие пироги!", которую мы все слышим повсеместно.

Comment: "Их едят а они пищат" - это вроде бы об устрицах? А поговорка была про пироги в Рязани: "У нас в Рязани - пироги с глазами. Их едят, а они глядят".

Answer (score 0):

Я, если честно, слышал только "Вот такие пироги" =)

Answer (score 0):

"Вот такие пирожки с котятами", - слышала лет восемь назад.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, в народе многие десятки лет - не поручусь за сотни, но и это возможно, - бытует представление о том, что недобросовестные изготовители уличной еды - пирожков, беляшей, а также пришедшей к нам позже шаурмы, - могут заменять дорогое качественное мясо кошатиной. Вероятно, прецеденты на самом деле бывали. Как некая "страшилка", периодически вновь и вновь возникает история о том, что якобы кто-то где-то нашёл в пирожке коготь... Дело в том, что кошачье мясо, в отличие от собачьего, сохраняющего характерный "собачий" запах, по запаху и вкусу совершенно не отличается от мяса кролика; бывали случаи, когда кошачью тушку без головы, лапок и хвоста продавали под видом кроличьей. (Именно поэтому продавцы кроличьего мяса оставляют неободранными лапки тушки - чтобы было видно, что это - не кошка). Впрочем, для успокоения мнительных могу сказать, что употребление в пищу кошки, хотя и противоречит нашей культуре, безвредно и на человеке никак не сказывается.

Comment: А откуда выражение пошло? Дополните ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

У нас на Урале так называют пирожки с ливером.